# Datepicker appears behind a wrap div.

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, apex

I have a form on my website for clients to specify what product they want. The job of the form is to collect that data. One on the form fields is meant to specify the deadline for the project. Using datepicker I want to populate the field based on what the customer picks on the calendar. And it does exactly that. The problem is when The calendar appears, it pop ups behind a wrapsemibox and I want it in front of it. right below the input field. Here is the codes.

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>


<apex:inputField value="{!Service_Order__c.Project_Deadline__c}" 
html-placeholder="Please allow 8 weeks" 
id="datepicker" required="true" styleClass="form-control" />
```

Those two codes produce an out put like this :

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqB93.png)
[When you zoom out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq2tT.png)

Comment: Try `z-index` property on datepicker

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:inputField style='z-index:999;position:relative;'
```

Comment: Can you explain how to apply the code, how does this fix the issue? Consider that this post will be used by other users for reference in the future and this is a knowledge sharing site so you should consider being a bit more verbose in your answers